# Multi select only as a dropdown selector and user input disabled

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, dropdownbox, kendo-multiselect

Thanks for the response.

```
1. keypress event works, but I am not able to remove the cursor also from the multiselect. As per the requirement, even the cursor(text input cursor: "I") should not be available. It should just be a dropdown where the user can select the option.

2. I am getting data from URL and passing it as an object to "value" in multiselect example
```

value : getFieldValues() //Here in the function I return the object of the values that I set to the multiselect on initialisation.

example: [Object {PLACE="Bangalore", TYPE="city"}, Object { PLACE="Anderson", TYPE="city"}] is the returned object from getFieldValues().

The values in the multiselect are set twice to "Bangalore". Please let me know why is this happening?

Please find the example w.r.t to the issue

http://jsbin.com/asAdurO/1/edit

Thanks, Bharath

Answer (score 0):

```
Enclose the MULTISELECT in a div/span and add this code in script :

$(#divID).on('keypress', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();    
  });
```